# Passing messages from child task to parent in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, task

I have a wcf service that will spawn multiple tasks. I'm looking for a way for each task to provider information back to the parent thread (and ultimately to a client via a data contract)

The work to be done is in a separate class. In the main class I'm starting my tasks like this:

```
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
        Task[] arrTask = new Task[lstTasks.Count];
        int i = 0;

        foreach(LabParser classA in lstTasks)
            {
                try
                {
                   var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(clsa.ProcessLabs,token);
                    arrTask[i] = t;
                    i++;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    string tmp = e.ToString();
                }
            }
            Task.WaitAll(arrTask);
```

So in classA.ProcessLabs I'm going quite a bit of work. I want to be able to send a message back to this parent some information about what the thread's current status is.
I'm used to doing this in vb using delegates and events and raising an event. 
I can't seem to find an equivalent way to do this in C#.

Answer (score 2):

The standard means of reporting status/progress is via [`IProgress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298.aspx) interface, often via the default [`Progress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692.aspx) implementation.

> I'm used to doing this in vb using delegates and events and raising an event. I can't seem to find an equivalent way to do this in c#.

The same technique should work in C#, as well.  C# supports delegates and events with the same basic feature set as VB.Net, so you should be able to directly port this code if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Task<T>`, which allows the callback to return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Using delegates and events will work in C#, the syntax will be different compared to VB.

Defenition of the delegate

```
/// <summary>
/// Update count delegate handler
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">Obect sender</param>
/// <param name="ca">Event arguments</param>
public delegate void UpdateCountHandler(object sender, TaskArgs ca);

/// <summary>
/// Update count event
/// </summary>
public event UpdateCountHandler UpdateCount;
```

To call the event.

```
// Call on the event
 this.UpdateCount(this, tsk);
```

Comment: When using delegates you almost never need to define your own.  You can virtually always use one of the system defined delegates instead, usually `Action` or `Func`.

Comment: Agreed, but before you can use the system defined delegates one has to understand how to create their own and how they work before you can start using short cuts.

Comment: Why is that?  You virtually never need to define your own delegates; you can almost always use the system delegates instead.  If/when you find yourself in the rare instance where you need to create your own, it's simple enough to look up how.  I don't see knowing the syntax for how to define a delegate as being something that really helps you understand what a delegate is.